# iPhone screenshot different colour when displayed

Tags: iphone, png, uiimage, screenshot, color-space

I've taken a screenshot of my iPhone app running and I'd like to use that image as a png to be drawn by the app instead of generated graphics.

When I take the screenshot, it looks fine. However, when that is saved as a PNG file, added to the Xcode project and then displayed back on the screen of the phone (or simulator) the colours are different.

Can anyone explain to me why it's changing? (I'm guessing there's a colour space conversion happening).

How can I stop this from changing?

Comment: I managed to get it to look better by opening the image in Preview and selecting Tools -> Assign Profile... and trying various profiles. Seems that there is indeed some colour space correction/processing going on. I'd still like to know exactly what the colour profile should be set to so that a screen snapshot from the iPhone can be shown in the iPhone and look exactly the same as the original.

Answer (score 0):

You might be saving the png image with some incorrect settings which is either reducing the quality or number of colors used. Try the PNG-24 with transparency to see if that helps at all.